# ExtJs - Allowing user to modify position of form fields using drag and drop

Tags: layout, extjs, drag-and-drop, position, form-fields

We have been developing our application using ExtJs 4.0.7, and now we have a new feature request which will allow user to set the position of form fields, as per his choice, using drag and drop.

For example, if currently a form has fields arranged in rows, then the user can pick these fields and arrange them in columns, or he can move a field from first row to second etc..

The user is also allowed to save this layout and when he opens the screen again then he gets to see the fields arranged in the same manner he saved.

I have not been able to locate any example in ExtJS carrying such a functionality, so I was wondering if this is possible in ExtJS?

Also, as the user is allowed to save the layout, thus, will this involve storing of ExtJs code in database or dynamic generation of ExtJS code from server side.

Looking forward to guidance at this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The only example of such a beast I have seen is the Sencha Designer. It saved the complete JSON object that represents the form config ... I suppose it's doable, but good luck :)

Comment: Thanks for the post DmitryB. Saving the complete JSON is what we too had been thinking of, but was wondering if something in this could be supported by State Manager of ExtJs. Any idea on that?